# DTO List Mapping / Streaming

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, set, java-stream

It's maybe an easy problem but I won't get the best solution. My method like looks this:

```
public static MlpConfigDto toMlpConfigDto(MlpConfig mlpConfig) {
    return new MlpConfigDto().setActivationFunction(mlpConfig.getActivationFunction().getType().name())
            .setBatchSize(mlpConfig.getBatchSize()).setDescription(mlpConfig.getDescription())
            .setEpochNumber(mlpConfig.getEpochNumber()).setId(mlpConfig.getId())
            .setLastUpdated(mlpConfig.getLastUpdated())
            .setLayers(new List<LayerDto>(
                    mlpConfig.getLayers().stream().map(layer -> new ModelMapper().map(layer, LayerDto.class)))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

The last part of  course does not work because there is no `new List<LayerDto>` in Java. With a `Set` this works like a charm but I need a `List` here. How to do it the easiest way for `List`s then?

For `Set`s it would look like this:

```
.setLayers(new HashSet<LayerDto>(
    mlpConfig.getLayers().stream().map(layer -> new ModelMapper().map(layer, LayerDto.class)))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
}
```

Comment: Hmm, does this compile? Looks like you're invoking `collect` on `Set`, or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: did you mean `new ArrayList<LayerDto>` instead of the interface? and yes you don't need the wrapping when its already collected to the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line returns a list:

```
mlpConfig.getLayers()
    .stream()
    .map(layer -> new ModelMapper().map(layer, LayerDto.class))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

There is no need to wrap it into another collection.

Comment: @CptDayDreamer no problem, have a great day!